# chown permission command later black screen el capitan

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-elcapitan

hello i have blank screen error after user password login and progressbar complate progress later i did before

sudo chown -R $( whoami)

later gives me yellow popup bla bla.kext dont load about 15-20 popups

i did restart and now im trying to login my mac user and password entry later i clicked login everything good but when progress bar finished gives black screen and still waiting there i booted my mac with usb and im on now terminal screen how can i resolve this problem ? maybe i do back orginal settings etc ?

any idea ?

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: But you need to run "fix permissions" from Disk Util.  If you cannot do that you are looking at reinstalling OSX.

Comment: how can i open disk utility ? when boot

Comment: [Cmd+R](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201314).

Comment: @trojanfoe im trying

Comment: i did fix but no way i have installer app in my applications and i have usb disk but when i do usb installer on terminal gives sudo command dont found